# Using Ant with Jenkins, php lint does not fail on invalid unchanged files

Tags: php, ant, lint

Excuse the title, as I have no idea what it should be.

I'm using Ant to do php lint for Jenkins CI and the process caches the results (cache.properties). However, if the file does not change, then then the next pass does not fail, but it should as the file is still invalid. Is that normal behavior? How can I tell it not to cache the failed file or is there another way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution that I came up with (I'm running Jenkins on Windows, so adjust for the OS accordingly):

Install the plugin: Post build task (it's old, so it will install as Hudson Post build task).

Configure a Post build task (that's the section) called Post build task (the plugin) as follows:

Log text: Errors parsing
Script: del cache.properties

Clunky, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend switching to another php linter.. for example if you are using sublime text => https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter-phplint

Comment: I'm using this with Jenkins, and I don't know how to integrate another linter.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you, I would really recommend using simple text editors for any coding

Comment: It's not for coding, Jenkins is a CI.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue similar to this, what I did was to remove the `<modified />` node from the fileset for the lint target. See example below.

This is what I had when I was facing the issue

```
<target name="lint"
         unless="lint.done"
         description="Perform syntax check of sourcecode files">
  <apply executable="php" taskname="lint">
   <arg value="-l" />

   <fileset dir="${basedir}/src">
    <include name="**/*.php" />
    <modified />
   </fileset>

   <fileset dir="${basedir}/tests">
    <include name="**/*.php" />
    <modified />
   </fileset>
  </apply>

  <property name="lint.done" value="true"/>
 </target>
```

This is what my lint target looks like now.

```
<target name="lint"
         unless="lint.done"
         description="Perform syntax check of sourcecode files">
  <apply executable="php" taskname="lint">
   <arg value="-l" />

   <fileset dir="${basedir}/src">
    <include name="**/*.php" />
   </fileset>

   <fileset dir="${basedir}/tests">
    <include name="**/*.php" />
   </fileset>
  </apply>

  <property name="lint.done" value="true"/>
 </target>
```

I hope this helps someone

Comment: Yes, this does check every file, every time, but for large projects like ours, that takes a very, very, very long time (vs only those files modified).

Comment: I see @KeithDavis, how did you resolve the issue though?

Comment: See my answer below. I have a post build task delete the cache.properties file if "Errors parsing" exists in the output.